# To use servers behind firewall for boinc for public welfare

Tags: proxy, firewall, boinc

I have join boinc for public welfare.
I have 7 servers with 4 cores behind firewall which is not in using currently and may be empty for one year or life.Because no one care for the project which use these servers. So I want to use them to contribute for public welfare with boinc.

The problem is that none of these server can access internet and boinc need to download tasks and upload result by internet. The good news is that 2 of these servers can be accessed by internet in one way.

Because the port of 80 can be accessed by internet, so I think if I can use some software to be a proxy which listen in port 80, use an income connection to transfer info between boinc and public welfare project servers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded a socks proxy source code of JAVA. And then I modified it as two projects. One act as a proxy( named proxy-A) in an server which can access internet. Another act as a proxy(named proxy-B) in the server behind firewall.
The procedure is:
1. Proxy-A connect to the proxy-B and keep the connection.
2. The servers behind firewall connect to proxy-B by socks protocal.
3. proxy-B request proxy-A to begin a new connection to proxy-B by the connection in procedure 1.
4.  proxy-A connect to proxy-B.
5. proxy-B send the request to proxy-A.
6. proxy-A connect to server on internet and retrieve the information.
7. proxy-A send the information to proxy-B.
8. proxy-B send the result to the servers behind firewall.